# Google Actions on a Website?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Can you like with the Test Simulator have an embedded Google Action or use a Live chat style bot on a website with Google Actions responses? Are there any code labs or third party platforms that do this?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow has a Web Agent you can embed. Head over at Integrations and enable Web Demo. Once you do you'll get an IFrame where you can embed your code in a HTML page

[image]

Documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/web-demo

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know about the DF embed but it doesn't work with Actions on Google, it just works with DF and you cannot change the design.

Comment: Yeah you cannot integrate Actions on Google, that's only available for Devices supporting the Google Assistant, This is your best option

Comment: Should be doable as Google Actions works through the Firebase Functions on Node. Surely just with using some HTTP responses someone has built something? If it can work on the test simulator then why not? Very confused as to why this has not been done.

Comment: you don't need Firebase Functions to host an Action. You can use AWS Lambda, Digital Ocean etc.. In the End it's Dialogflow that will be handling everything. You can probably develop your own Dialogflow web chat but this is the one provided by Dialogflow

Comment: Again, than you for the reply but DF is just the NLU with some addons and is a library that Google Actions uses. Google Actions is core to the serverless architecture I have built with Firestore, Google AI API and other services. Having Google Actions on Firebase Functions for me works but not having a way to embed this in a website to show is frustrating. Just got to think of Actions as just for Assistant and Home but it is frustrating that the Test Simulator can be on a web but we can't.